# Pagination and filtering in TypeScript and TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

How can I create a function for pagination and filtering with typeorm?

I am using the `queryBuilder()`, But I don't know how to create a function to divide the results into pages and results on one page.

Here's what I've tried so far but it does not work:

```
async getPaginatedAndFilteringUsers(dto: PaginationUserDto): Promise<User[]> {
    
    const user = this.conn.getRepository(Employee)
      .createQueryBuilder('user ')
      .orderBy('user.id', dto.order)
      .skip(dto.rowsPerPage)
      .take(dto.page);

    return user;
}
```

I want to create a function for query parameters like this:

```
localhost:3000/user?page=1&rowsPerPage=15&orderBy=DESC
```

How can I do this with TypeORM?

Comment: You should give more context to the people. What do you mean by "it not work"?
Did it returned less than you expected? Show the raw query generated by function call.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I see that you did not execute the query. So, add the `.getMany()` at the end of the query chain:

```
getPaginatedAndFilteringUsers(dto: PaginationUserDto): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.conn.getRepository(Employee)
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .orderBy('user.id', dto.order)
      .skip(dto.rowsPerPage)
      .take(dto.page)
      .getMany();
}
```

---

Secondly, I have no idea what do you put in `PaginationUserDto`. I hope, that you put to it some users' info and pagination parameters like `page`, `rowsPerPage` and `orderBy`. If not, that's the second point to fix your issue: you need to parse query params and put it to your `dto` (because of you use these params from `dto`)

---

I hope it would be helpful

Comment: @comodo was it helpful for you?

Comment: This is WRONG!take: pageSize,
            skip: pageSize * pageNumber

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in pure TypeORM is as follows:

```
const getPaginatedAndFilteringUsers = async (
  dto: PaginationUserDto,
): Promise<User[]> => {
  const [user, count] = await User.findAndCount({
    order: { id: "DESC" },
    skip: dto.rowsPerPage,
    take: dto.page,
  });
  return paginatedUserInfo({
    user: user,
    totalCount: count,
  });
};
```

> The totalCount is not considered the paginated result it will
> return a full row count